# Kotlin - Building a map of lists from a flat list in pragmatic way

Tags: kotlin

I have a Kotlin flat list made of objects, something like...

```
    data class Someone(var name: String, var age: Int)

    val someoneList = listOf<Someone>(Someone("Joe", 12), Someone("Bill", 15), Someone("Nancy", 12))
```

...and I'd like to easy convert that to a map, the key being the age, and the value a list of the names.
Pretty sure there is a Kotlin way to do that, but I'm a bit puzzled about the examples I can find about associate, associateBy and all this kind of stuff!

Thanks for your help!

VR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kotlin has `groupBy` function, which take two parameters, keyselector and value selector lambdas

```
val someoneList = listOf<Someone>(Someone("Joe", 12), Someone("Bill", 15), Someone("Nancy", 12))
val grouped = someoneList.groupBy ({ it.age }, {it.name})
```

Comment: The difference between `groupBy()` and `associateBy()` is that `groupBy()` allows multiple values for the same key, and so each key maps to a list; while `associateBy()` allows only one value for each key (keeping only the last if there are more than one).

Comment: @gidds I think this comment should be in question instead :)

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer!